# How do I implement output variables in powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I realize "output variables" is probably the wrong terminology here which is why my google searching has failed me. I'm guessing it revolves around explicitly setting variable scope, but I've tried reading the [about_Scopes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes) doc and it's just not clicking for me.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is implement the equivalent of the `-SessionVariable` argument from [Invoke-RestMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) in my own module's function. In other words, I need a string parameter that turns into a variable in the caller's scope.

```
function MyTest
{
    param([string]$outvar)

    # caller scoped variable magic goes here
    set-variable -Name $outvar -value "hello world"

    # normal function output to pipeline here
    Write-Output "my return value"
}

# calling the function initially outputs "my return value"
MyTest -outvar myvar

# referencing the variable outputs "hello world"
$myvar
```

For bonus points, how do things change (if at all) if I'm wrapping an existing function that has its own output variable and I want to effectively pass through the output variable name?

```
function MyWrapper
{
    param([string]$SessionVariable)

    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://myhost" -SessionVariable $SessionVariable

    # caller scoped variable magic goes here
    set-variable -Name $SessionVariable -value $SessionVariable
}

# calling the wrapper outputs the normal results from Invoke-RestMethod
MyWrapper -SessionVariable myvar

# calling the variable outputs the WebRequestSession object from the inner Invoke-RestMethod call
$myvar
```

P.S. If it matters, I'm trying to keep the module compatible with Powershell v3+.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Mathias R. Jessen propose solution, which work well, when not defined in module. But not, if you put it in module. So, I provide another solution, which works, when put in module.

In advanced function (one which use `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute) you can use `$PSCmdlet.SessionState` to refer to `SessionState` of a caller. Thus, you can use `$PSCmdlet.SessionState.PSVariable.Set('Name' ,'Value')` to set variables in caller's `SessionState`.

Note: this solution will not work if not defined in module or if called from the same module, where it defined.

```
New-Module {
    function MyTest1 {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param([string]$outvar)
        $PSCmdlet.SessionState.PSVariable.Set($outvar, 'Some value')
    }
    function MyTest2 {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param([string]$outvar)
        # -Scope 1 not work, because it executed from module SessionState,
        # and thus have separate hierarchy of scopes
        Set-Variable -Name $outvar -Value 'Some other value' -Scope 1
    }
    function MyTest3 {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param([string]$outvar)
        # -Scope 2 will refer to global scope, not the caller scope,
        # so variable with same name in caller scope will hide global variable
        Set-Variable -Name $outvar -Value 'Some other value' -Scope 2
    }
} | Out-Null

& {
    $global:a = 'Global value'
    MyTest1 a
    $a
    $global:a
    ''
    MyTest2 a
    $a
    $global:a
    ''
    MyTest3 a
    $a
    $global:a
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and demonstration. This does seem like a more correct way of accomplishing the task even though in my particular case it would probably be ok to hide the global variable.

Answer (score 9):

There's no need to attempt to implement this yourself, `-OutVariable` is a [Common Parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters).

Add a [`CmdletBinding` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute) to your `param` block to get these for free:

```
function MyTest {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()

    return "hello world"
}

MyTest -OutVariable testvar
```

`$testvar` now holds the string value "hello world"

For your second example, where you need to set a value in the caller scope in addition to pipeline output, use the `-Scope` option with `Set-Variable`:

```
function MyTest {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([string]$AnotherVariable)

    if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($AnotherVariable)){
        Set-Variable -Name $AnotherVariable -Value 'more data' -Scope 1
    }

    return "hello world"
}

MyTest -AnotherVariable myvar
```

`$myvar` in the caller scope now contains the string value "more data". The `1` value passed to the `Scope` parameter means "1 level up"

Comment: Ironically, I'm already using CmdletBinding in my actual function. But unless I misunderstand how this works, I don't think I can use it because the function already has real output that I want to keep and this would take the place of that, right?  I will update the examples in my question to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: @RyanBolger Updated answer

Comment: Scope "1 level up". Beautiful. Thanks a ton!

Comment: ... or "immediate parent", you get the idea :-) your most welcome.

Comment: I'm finding that in my module I need to specify "-Scope 2" for it to make it back to the caller. Is that because there's an extra level due to being a module? Or perhaps because my module functions are in files being dot sourced from the psm1 file?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen `Set-Variable -Scope 1` will not going work properly, if function defined in module. Modules use separate `SessionState` with separate scope hierarchy, so that "immediate parent" will not be caller.

Comment: @RyanBolger `-Scope 2` will likely refer to global scope, not the caller scope (unless it is the same). And yes, it is because you are in module.